# Import and set bradley hand for android app

Tags: android, iphone, fonts

I recently developed an iPhone app and trying to make a similar version to the android.

Everything goes well, apart from android doesn't supports bradley hand as a text font used on my buttons and labels.

I know you can possibly import your own text font, but I searched all over google and couldn't find any hints on:

- How to do this, or perhaps an helpful tutorial somewhere online
- **But more importantly**, where can I get the bradley hand font source to import?

I use eclipse SDK on mac.

Any senoirs can give me a help with it?

Cheers
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create the folder `assets/fonts` in your project directory.
2) Place the font-file in the `fonts` directory
3) In the activity where you'd like to use the font, do this:

`private static Typeface sTypeface;

if (sTypeface == null) {

            sTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/you_font_filename.ttf");

        }

        TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.you_textview);

        mTextView .setTypeface(sTypeface);`

Comment: That's bralliant, any idea where you can get a bunch of font sources? I need the bradley handed font urgently.

Comment: I don't know if it's a "free" font, but you can download a .ttf-file here: http://fontzone.net/font-download/Bradley+Hand+ITC/